# How to dynamically set the background color in an ASCX file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, kentico, ascx

I have an ASCX file called `AegHero` where I have the a markup for a WebPart. I also have a `BackgroundColor` property that holds a class name, that class name corresponds to a class with a specific background color.

I think that my issue is that I am not properly defining the values in the code behind. I am using a drop-down menu to have the user select a color:

[image]

Here is my AegHero.ascx:

```
<asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
    <div id="mainHeroContainer" class="fullWidth-hero-container <%= BackgroundColor %>">
        <div class="fullWidth-hero-container-inner">
            <h2 class="fillWidth-hero-title"><%=Title %></h2>
            <p class="fillWidth-hero-subtilte"><%=SubTitle %></p>

            <% if (ShowButton)
                {%>
            <a class="btn button" href="<%= ButtonUrl %>"><%= ButtonLabel %></a>
            <%} %>
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

Here is my code behind:

```cs
public partial class AegHero : GenericWebPart
    {
        protected string Title => Html("Title", string.Empty);
        protected string SubTitle => Html("subTitle", string.Empty);
        protected bool ShowButton => GetBooleanValue("ShowButton", false);
        protected string ButtonUrl => StringProperty("ButtonUrl", string.Empty);
        protected string ButtonLabel => StringProperty("ButtonLabel", string.Empty);
        protected string BackgroundColor
        {
            get { return StringProperty("BackgroundColor", string.Empty); }
            set { BackgroundColor = value; }
        }

        public override void OnContentLoaded()
        {
            base.OnContentLoaded();

            if (BackgroundColor.CompareTo("#002147") == 0)
            {
                BackgroundColor = "perussian-backGround";
            }
            else if (BackgroundColor.CompareTo("#0077c2") == 0)
            {
                BackgroundColor = "lochmara-backGround";
            }
            else if (BackgroundColor.CompareTo("#858e99") == 0)
            {
                BackgroundColor = "gray-backGround";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here are my css classes:

```css
.gray-backGround {
  background: #858e99;
}

.lochmara-backGround {
  background: #0077c2;
}

.perussian-backGround {
  background: #002147;
}
```

I am trying to set the `<%= BackgroundColor %>` according to a hexadecimal value that I receive; however, when I look in my chrome inspector, the class is not changed. How can I properly get the value from the backgroundColor property and set it on a `<div>`?

Chrome inspector:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to look at how to [create/develop custom webparts](https://docs.xperience.io/k12sp/developing-websites/developing-web-parts) to get started.  I say this because you're public properties are not retrieving the stored value from the webpart in the UI.  Here's a standard property example:

```
public string BackgroundColor
{
    get
    {
        return DataHelper.GetNotEmpty(GetValue("BackgroundColor"), string.Empty);
    }
    set
    {
        SetValue("BackgroundColor", value);
    }
}
```

The `GetValue("BackgroundColor")` method, takes the string name of the column you created on the webpart property in the Kentico UI and retrieves the value stored in the database for a given page/template.  This allows the editor to select or enter a color from the front end Kentico UI and allows you to use it in code.

Read up more on the docs and it should get you moving in the right direction.

Comment: I added your piece of code, but that didn't fix it for me either? Do you have any other suggestions? I am using a drop-down menu to have the user select a color

Comment: Can you explain more what "isn't working"?  Is it returning a value at all?  If so, what was the value?

Comment: your solution works, I misspelled the name of the property, that is why it was I was getting an error. Thank you!